# How to set the geo location through code

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, geolocation

I'm writing a test which opens a map using `Selenium`.
The problem is that the map is opened at my current location - however I want to have it opened at a different location (different country).

I've adjusted the location using the Chrome devtools by programatically going to Sensors.
How can I achieve the same behaviour in `Java`?
I have tried the following code without any success..

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("pro`enter code here`file.default_content_settings.geolocation", 2);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", jsonObject);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success){ var position = {'coords' : { 'latitude': '55.751244', 'longitude': '37.618423'}}; success(position);}");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To override the geo-location with Chrome:

```java
Map prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 1); // 1:allow 2:block

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

((LocationContext)driver).setLocation(new Location(37.774929, -122.419416, 0));
driver.get("https://html5demos.com/geo/");
```

Comment: I tried the same for appium, but the location is not set in my application. I used Appium driver and code as follows *driver.setLocation(new Location(10.79,78.70, 1000));*

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of using Selenium to open a Google map at a given location:

```
public void openGoogleMap(final String latitude, final String longitude, final int zoom) throws InterruptedException {
    // Optional, if not specified, WebDriver will search your path for chromedriver.
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/user/Apps/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/maps/" + "@" + latitude + "," + longitude + "," + zoom + "z?hl=en");
    Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
    driver.quit();
}
```

And here is an example test which demonstrates the usage of the method:

```
@Test
public void testOpenGoogleMap() throws InterruptedException {
    String latitude = "55.751244";
    String longitude = "37.618423";
    int zoom = 15;
    selenium.openGoogleMap(latitude, longitude, zoom);
}
```

Note: here *selenium* is a variable of type *Selenium* which has method *openGoogleMap()*

Comment: The OP did not said they wanted to open _Google_ Maps.

Comment: @hldev "open a Google map" doesn't contradict "open a map", correct? Google map is a map, isn't it? So I used it as a concrete example. Why don't you post an answer with a different map provider?

Comment: your answer is specific to Google Maps, works only for that, it's not an example solution applicable to actual question.